# How to spit in the black pool?

Tags: the-secret-world

During the League of Monster Slayers admission quest, you are required to spit in the Black Pool.

I found the pool, fought some monsters in and around it, but cannot spit in the pool itself.

How can I accomplish this tier of the quest?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are "emotes", that is, gestures and movements you can trigger from the chat box. They are much like IRC and such; enter "/help" and you get a list of all the available emotes.

"/spit", then, will allow you to spit - so stand by the pool and do it!

Comment: I can confirm the emote will do it.  Take care not to step IN the pool while you do it!

Comment: type "/spit" in chat works